# How to update record by property like email in objectify datastore?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify

i want to update password field in objectify datastore. i only have email value. how can i write update query for it? . Here is my code :

```
 Query<Gamer> query = ofy().load().type(Gamer.class);

 query = query.filter("email =", emailobj);
```

Here i am getting filter data , now want to update password of this record.
please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to update one record (the user profile corresponding to the email).

1/ Load this entity from the datastore (you get a java object, i.e. an instance of the Gamer class):

```
Gamer gamer = ofy().load().type(Gamer.class).filter("email =", emailobj).first().now();
```

2/ Modify your java object as desired (standard way, nothing special here, e.g. through setters)

3/ Save the java object in Objectify

```
ofy().save().entity(gamer).now();
```

I advise that you read the Objectify documentation: https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki

Comment: i am getting NullPointerException , here is my code: Gamer gamer = ofy().load().type(Gamer.class).filter("email =", email).first().now();
        gamer.update(email, password);
        ofy().save().entity(gamer).now();
        return gamer;

Comment: Look in the logs on the Cloud console at which line you get this Exception

Comment: Is your emailobj a String?

Comment: Ok. Again, do you find in the logs on the Cloud console at which line you get this Exception?

Comment: If you get an NullPointerException the console should show you at which line in your Endpoint class this exception occurs. Look at https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs_viewer_v1 or https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs_viewer_v2